# Requirements in order to control a Linux controller via MegaRAID Storage Management on Windows

Tags: megaraid

I installed the MegaRAID Storage Management on Windows VM and under Server Details I can enter a server IP.

In my case the MegaRAID controller is running under XenServer 6.5. But when I enter the XenServer host IP the program does not find it.

Error Message:

[image]

**My question:**

What I have to install on the XenServer host in order the Windows Version of the MegaRAID Storage Manager can access it? What is meant with `server not installed in the host system`? Which `server`?

Comment: I can only guess, but perhaps you are searching for the "Linux Version of the MegaRAID Storage Manager". Which itself should be listening on the ip you are using in the "Windows Version of the MegaRAID Storage Manager" ;-)

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I could find a solution in the web and you was right... Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Phillip -Zyan K Lee- Stockmann](https://superuser.com/users/616687/phillip-zyan-k-lee-stockmann) was right.

This article https://www.darrellenns.com/wp/post/231 had the solution. I followed the steps - apart from the SNMP part which I don't use.

Now it works perfectly!